# Ajax Dial Control?

Tags: javascript, ajax, controls, charts

Does anyone know of a free Ajax Dial control?

I'm looking for a speedometer, percentage etc control.

I'd expect to find loads of these as they seem to be in fashion at the moment in UI Design but I've yet to find any good looking free ones, and the only commercial one I've found costs $800 for a whole library of controls most of which I don't need.

**Update**

The context is to show a live (or as live as possible) measure of performance, I'm looking for it for a variety of applications, such as showing how close a team is to it's target etc.

Comment: Could you perhaps describe what you will be using it for?  Might give people some info.

Comment: Are you already using a Javascript library? That would narrow down the search to "not in this totally unrelated library I don't want to bring up conflicts with by installing alongside the one I'm already using" options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the gauge from the Google Charts set, which you can animate:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#gauge_interaction

You'll have to plumb in your own Ajax-ness to retrieve the data - I believe the Google Web Toolkit can do the integration (never tried, just a guess)

Answer (score 1):

Dojo has a great widget for exactly this, see [AnalogGauge](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/widget/AnalogGauge) for usage examples. They can be updated on the fly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not ajax, but almost free
http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/

Answer (score 0):

A very literal set of javascript guages can be found here:
http://www.ejschart.com/examples/other/advancedAnalogGauge.html

If you're willing to use some silverlight in your markup, this is pretty nice looking:
www.codeplex.com/SilverlightGaugeDemo